# dynamic url for jquery tabpanel

Tags: jquery, struts2, tabs, tabpanel, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2-jquery plugin for tabpanel. Check out below code

```
<table width="98%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <s:select list="appList" id="appList" name="selectedApp"
          headerKey="-1" onchange="getApplicationValue(this);"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <s:url var="urlVar" value="actionValue">
        <s:param name="calledAction">actionName</s:param>
  </s:url>

      <sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" selectedTab="0" cssStyle="width:100%">

      <sj:tab id="pendingTab" href="%{urlVal}" key="key" target="div1" 
    loadingText="Loading..." indicator="indicator">
    <sj:div id="pendingDiv" indicator="indicator" >
    </sj:div> 
  </sj:tab>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<script language="javascript">
        var selectedTab;

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#remotetabs').tabs({
            select:function(event,ui) { //bind click event to link
                selectedTab=ui.index;
            }
         });
    });

    function getApplicationValue(){

        $( "#remotetabs" ).tabs( "load", selectedTab);
}
</script>
```

My requirement is

> 1. each tabs calling url, perform database operation and shows data in that tab
> 2. changing on value of combo box above tabpanel fires current selected tab with passing the value of current selected value in combobox
> 3. on change of combobox, data should appear in current selected tab

problem: req1 and req3 are working fine, but for req2 I am not able to pass the selected combobox value to my action class as current page is already loaded. changing the tab panel doesnt bind my class variable to action class. Please help me figuring out, how would I pass my combo box value to my action class (without loading the whole page/changing tab)

this is what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/rohanparekh/ZvtRM/3/

Comment: this is what it looks like : http://jsfiddle.net/rohanparekh/ZvtRM/ i want to pass selected combo box value to my action class without calling action

Comment: @cpoDesign: you can't put code with taglibs in jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1):

The code is unbalanced.

`sj:tabbedpanel` is never closed by a closing tag.